# OpenOffice Writer. Macro : replacing the selected text

Tags: macros, replace, selection, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I'm trying to create a macro that would change and replace the current selected text in OpenOffice Writer.

So far my macro looks like this:

```
sub myReplaceSelection
Dim oDoc
Dim oVC
Dim R As String

oDoc = ThisComponent
oVC = oDoc.CurrentController.getViewCursor
If Len(oVC.String) > 0 Then
   R = processSelection(oVC.String)
   'replace the selection:
   'which function should I call here ? <------------------
   '
EndIf
End sub

Function processSelection( s As String) As String
 '... ok , this part works fine
End Function
```

How can I replace the current selected text with my String 'R' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it:

```
If Len(oVC.String) > 0 Then
  oVC = oDoc.CurrentController.getViewCursor
  If Len(oVC.String) > 0 Then
  Dim document   as object
  dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
  args1(0).Name = "Text"
  args1(0).Value = processSelection(oVC.String)
  document = oDoc.CurrentController.Frame
  dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:InsertText", "", 0, args1())
EndIf
```

Comment: or even simplier:  'oVC.setString( processSelection(oVC.String)) '